# SQL - Creating View with last row for each group (large Dataset)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, view

So I'm supposed to create a View that's based on the last row of each group in a huge Dataset
(33918340 rows) so performance is the key issue. For example getting the last turnover for each bank account from the turnover table. I'm using something like

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM turnover t1 LEFT JOIN turnover t2
ON (t1.bankaccnumber = t2.bankaccnumber AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

the performance is not very good and I later have to add additional joins related to the customer etc.. ( this is just an example )

are there better ways to do it (using Microsoft SQL Server 2014)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` or `rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by bankaccnumber order by id desc) as seqnum
      from turnover t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

That said, a correlated subquery often has slightly better performance:

```
select t.*
from turnover t
where t.id = (select max(t2.id) from turnover t2 where t2.bankaccnumber = t.bankaccnumber)
```

particularly with an index on `turnover(bankaccnumber, id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() to get last row for each group. Something like this.

```
with LastRow as
(
   SELECT t1.*, row_number()over (partition by bankaccnumber order by id desc)rn
   FROM turnover t1 
)
select * from LastRow where rn=1
```

here `row_number()over (partition by bankaccnumber order by id desc)` will create a sequential number started from 1 for each bankaccnumber in descending order of id.